# Android 4.2 Daydream when not docked or charging

Tags: android, sleep

Android 4.2 has a new 'interactive screensaver' option called Daydream which works when your device is either docked or charging or both.

I want to enable this feature ALWAYS, so it works even when the device is NOT docked or charging.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just defined what a daydream is. And you want to do something outside of it's definition. So I would say don't use a Daydream then.

Just make a full screen activity, or a live wallpaper, or install it as an app launcher and just take over the desktop.